# Additivity of squared Schatten $p$-norm with respect to spatial partition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory

Consider a Hilbert-Schmidt operator $A$ on $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ with integral kernel $A(x,y)$. Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ and $1_{\Omega}(x)$ denote its characteristic function as well as the corresponding multiplication operator. Note that by the triangle inequality
$$\lVert A\rVert_2 \leq \lVert 1_{\Omega} A \rVert_2 + \lVert 1_{\Omega^c} A \rVert_2,$$
where $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm. By the nice property that we can express $\lVert A \rVert_2$ as the $L^2 \times L^2$ norm of its kernel we also have the (in-)equality
$$\begin{align} \lVert A \rVert_2^2 & = \int_{\mathbb R^d} \int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert A(x,y)\rvert^2 \, dx \, dy \\ & = \int_{\Omega} \int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert A(x,y)\rvert^2 \, dx \, dy + \int_{\Omega^c} \int_{\mathbb R^d} \lvert A(x,y)\rvert^2 \, dx \, dy \\ & = \lVert 1_\Omega A \rVert_2^2 + \lVert 1_{\Omega^c} A \rVert_2^2 \end{align}$$
with squares on both sides. My question: Does this generalize to higher Schatten $p$-norms, $p>2$? That is, does
$$\lVert A \rVert_p^2 \leq \lVert 1_\Omega A\rVert_p^2 + \lVert 1_{\Omega^c} A\rVert_p^2$$ hold? If not, does anyone have a good counterexample? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is the triangle inequality for the Schatten $p/2$-norm.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see it now. More generally, for $A, B$ such that $A^*B = B^*A = 0$ we have $\lVert A + B \rVert_p^2 \leq \lVert A \rVert_p^2 + \lVert B \rVert_p^2$, right?

Comment: That is right, yes.